# Symfony 3: Twig 2.0 generate Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '(' with php 5.6

Tags: php, twig, symfony, php-7

After the twig update to 2.0 lauching my symfony application in app_dev causes this error.

> FatalErrorException in 93e60ea26910cdda85fa486e153005cae79d76b217a9156c35050e1e466ba8b1.php line 54:
>   Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '('

It's a cache file. This error happens only in PHP 5.6 but works fine in PHP 7.0.

This is the line in autogenerated cache file that cause the error:

```
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, (isset($context["title"]) || array_key_exists("title", $context) ? $context["title"] : (function () { throw new Twig_Error_Runtime('Variable "title" does not exist.', 3, $this->getSourceContext()); })()), "html", null, true);
```

Is there any configuration of the new Twig 2.0 to make it work with php 5.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Twig 2.0 requires php7, see the require block of [its composer.json](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2a86dde1288d7270169083d0e078dc7ebe0f48b6/composer.json).

You can still use twig 1.* in your project.